# How do i get wp gallery to add my images alt text

Tags: wordpress, image

So using wordpess.com
Is there a way to get alt text to show when inserting images as a gallery? The code only shows gallery id code and nothing more.
I need that alt text to get my images to rank in the serps.
The images are too large to insert as individual images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out while the gallery id code was the only image code showing in wp html view that viewing page source shows all the image details like alt text and file name are indeed there.